# Static parameter with different values in subclasses

Tags: java, parameters, static, subclass

I want to create a solution for the following problem without much redundancy:

I have an abstract class `Unit`, subclasses `SubUnit1` and `SubUnit2`. All `Unit`s have a `maxValue`, which differs from `SubUnit1` to `SubUnit2`, but should be the same for all instances of the same sub unit at any time.

I don't want to copy all the setters, getters or some kind of method around these values, because they are identical for all subclasses. I also don't want to use normal paramters and hand down the methods to subclasses and update every single instance of these subclasses if necessary. And somehow get the current value when I create a new instance.

Is there a way to declare some sort of static parameter and methods in the parent class `Unit`, that differ in the different subclasses?

Comment: no, you need to override a getter method in each class, which returns the proper value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a protected constructor in the parent class that accepts the value of the MAXVALUE

```
public abstract class Unit {
   private final int maximum;

   protected Unit(int maximum) {
      this.maximum = maximum;
   }

   public int getMaximum() {
      return maximum;
   }
}
```

Then in your derived classes you expose constructors that call the parent's constructor with a fixed value, unique per subclass.

```
public class SubUnit1 {
   private static final int SUBUNIT1_MAX = 10;

   public SubUnit1() {
      super(SUBUNIT1_MAX);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but using an `interface` you may express that a UNIT should have a MAXVALUE.

```
public interface IUnit
{
   public int getMaxValue();
}

public class SubUnit implements IUnit
{
   private static final int MAX_VALUE = 48;

   @Override
   public int getMaxValue() {
      return MAX_VALUE;
   }
}
```